# Ansible when condition registered from csv

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I'm using csv file as ingest data for my playbooks, but im having trouble with my when condition. it's either both task will skipped or both task will be ok, my objective is if ansible see the string in when condition it will skipped for the specific instance.

here is my playbook

```
- name: "Read ingest file from CSV return a list"
  community.general.read_csv:
     path: sample.csv
  register: ingest

- name: debug ingest
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.AWS_ACCOUNT }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ingest.list }}"
  register: account

- name: debug account
  debug:
    msg: "{{ account.results |  map(attribute='msg')  }}"
  register: accountlist

- name:
  become: yes
  become_user: awx
  delegate_to: localhost
  environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"
  block:
    - name: "Assume role"
      community.aws.sts_assume_role:
        role_arn: "{{ item.ROLE_ARN }}"
        role_session_name: "pm"
      with_items:
        - "{{ ingest.list }}"
      register: assumed_role
  when: "'aws-account-rnd' not in account.results | map(attribute='msg')"
```

here is the content of sample.csv

| HOSTNAME | ENVIRONMENT | AWS_ACCOUNT | ROLE_ARN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | dev | aws-account-rnd | arn:aws:iam::XXXX1 |
| test2 | uat | aws-account-uat | arn:aws:iam::XXXX2 |

my objective is to skipped all items in the csv file with aws-acount-rnd

Answer (score 1):

Your condition does not mention `item` so it will have the same result for all loop items.

Nothing you've shown requires the weird abuse of `debug` + `register` that you're doing, and it is in fact getting in your way.

```
- name: Read CSV file
  community.general.read_csv:
     path: sample.csv
  register: ingest

- name: Assume role
  community.aws.sts_assume_role:
    role_arn: "{{ item.ROLE_ARN }}"
    role_session_name: pm
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: true
  become_user: awx
  environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"
  loop: "{{ ingest.list }}"
  when: item.AWS_ACCOUNT != 'aws-account-rnd'
  register: assumed_role
```

If you'll always only care about one match you can also do this without a loop or condition at all:

```
- name: Assume role
  community.aws.sts_assume_role:
    role_arn: "{{ ingest.list | rejectattr('AWS_ACCOUNT', '==', 'aws-account-rnd') | map(attribute='ROLE_ARN') | first }}"
    role_session_name: pm
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: true
  become_user: awx
  environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"
  register: assumed_role
```

Comment: how can i pull the when when: item.AWS_ACCOUNT != 'aws-account-rnd' condition over a block

Comment: You cannot loop over a block, so it does not make sense to put that condition on a block.

Comment: noted on this. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> my objective is to skipped all items in the csv file with aws-acount-rnd

The multiple `debug` you have with `register`, seems to be a long-winded approach IMHO.

A simple task to `debug` the Role ARN, only if the account does not match `aws-acount-rnd`.

```yaml
- name: show ROLE_ARN when account not equals aws-account-rnd
  debug:
    var: item['ROLE_ARN']
  loop: "{{ ingest.list }}"
  when: item['AWS_ACCOUNT'] != 'aws-account-rnd'
```

This results in:

```
TASK [show ROLE_ARN when account not equals aws-account-rnd] **********************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'HOSTNAME': 'test1', 'ENVIRONMENT': 'dev', 'AWS_ACCOUNT': 'aws-account-rnd', 'ROLE_ARN': 'arn:aws:iam:XXXX1'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'HOSTNAME': 'test2', 'ENVIRONMENT': 'uat', 'AWS_ACCOUNT': 'aws-account-uat', 'ROLE_ARN': 'arn:aws:iam:XXXX2'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "AWS_ACCOUNT": "aws-account-uat",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "uat",
        "HOSTNAME": "test2",
        "ROLE_ARN": "arn:aws:iam:XXXX2"
    },
    "item['ROLE_ARN']": "arn:aws:iam:XXXX2"
}
```

The same logic can be used to pass the `item.ROLE_ARN` to `community.aws.sts_assume_role` task.